# How can I delete all windows user profiles EXCEPT for the ones I specify?

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

I am trying to remove all user profiles except for certain profiles I specify (administrator, Public, default, DOMAIN\administrator, etc)

I am able to do this successfully and exclude a single user profile, however I am having issues with the correct syntax to exclude multiple user profiles.  Here is the code I have found to successfully list all profiles except administrator:

`Get-CimInstance -ComputerName computer1,computer2 -Class Win32_UserProfile | Where-Object { $_.LocalPath.split('\')[-1] -ne 'administrator' }`

which I got from here:

https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-delete-user-profile/

I changed the -eq to a -ne to exclude the administrator profile, but I also want to exclude several other ones.

I think I need something like:

`Get-CimInstance -ComputerName computer1,computer2 -Class Win32_UserProfile | Where-Object { $_.LocalPath.split('\')[-1] -ne 'administrator','Public','default','DOMAIN\administrator' }`

however that does not seem to be working and it's only excluding the first name on the list (administrator).

What would be the correct syntax for this command?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Optional: Create an array with the list you want to keep like this:

```
$AccountsToKeep = @('administrator','Public','default','DOMAIN\administrator')
```

Then use this:

```
Get-CimInstance -ComputerName computer1,computer2 -Class Win32_UserProfile | Where-Object { $_.LocalPath.split('\')[-1] -notin $AccountsToKeep }
```

Hope this helps.

If you like this answer, please don't forget to accept it!

Comment: This works!  Thanks!  For anybody else reading this, to actually delete the user profiles, you need to add:

| Remove-CimInstance

at the end.

Answer (score -1):

```
$AccountsToKeep = @('administrator','Public','default','Contoso\Darrin.Thor')

Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_UserProfile | Where-Object { (!$_.Special) -and ($_.LocalPath.split('\')[-1] -notin $AccountsToKeep) } | Remove-CimInstance
```